# Javascript replace part with part of part in string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string something like

```
http://string.com/__11_22__/stuff
```

And I need to take this string and replace it with part of it so I end up with

```
http://string.com/11/stuff
```

or

```
http://string.com/22/stuff
```

Depending upon a if statement (is country blah or blah2). So if country is blah I would end up with `...11/...` if country is blah2 I would end up with `...22/...`

But I am a little confused with how to do it, the format will always be the same, two `_` followed by two digits followed by a `_` and 2 more digits then 2 more `_`

Comment: You need to show what you've tried.

Comment: Without some code attempted on your part, I'm not about to offer a full solution, but I can at least point you to the idea of using a "regular expression" or "regex". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this :

```
var url = 'http://string.com/__11_22__/stuff';
url = url.replace({ 
    blah: /__(\d+)_\d+__/, 
    blah2: /__\d+_(\d+)__/ 
}[country], '$1');
```

Or something more conventional :

```
var url = 'http://string.com/__11_22__/stuff';
switch (country) {
    case 'blah': url = url.replace(/__(\d+)_\d+__/, '$1'); break;
    case 'blah2': url = url.replace(/__\d+_(\d+)__/, '$1'); break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = 'http://string.com/__11_22__/stuff',
  replace = /__(\d\d)_(\d\d)__/;

s = s.replace(replace, function(match, part1, part2) {
  if (country == 'blah') {
    return part1;
  }
  else {
    return part2;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var isCountry =true;
var str = 'http://string.com/__11_22__/stuff';

str = str.replace(/__(\d{2})_(\d{2})__/, isCountry ? '$1' : '$2');
console.log(str); // 'http://string.com/11/stuff'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do 
    `var start = indexOf("__");`
you can after that do `var str.substring(start+2,start+4);` for the first and `str.substring(start+5,start+7);` for the second